# In C# how can we determine whether the following statement is for extending or implementing : public class MyClass1 : MyClass2?

Tags: c#

In C# how can we determine whether the following statement is for *extending* or *implementing* ?

```
public class MyClass1 : MyClass2
```

Comment: If `MyClass2` is a class then it is for *extending* else if it is an interface then it is for *implementing*.

Comment: @S.Akbari and if `MyClass2` is an abstract class?

Comment: @xanatos...Yes. I can't edit my comment anymore it should be: *else if it is an interface or abstract class then it is for implementing.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In C# how can we determine whether the following statement is for extending or implementing : public class MyClass1 : MyClass2 ?

You can't... `MyClass2` could be:

- an `abstract class` (like `System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>`), so you would be implementing it,
- an interface (like `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`), so you would be implementing it,
- an already implemented class (like `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`), so you would be extending it.

Note that by convention interfaces should begin with `I`, like `ISomething`. But there is no similar convention for abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

If  MyClass2 is an interface it is implemented by MyClass1

Comment: In addtion to that, Interfaces have an "I" in front of there name. Like IMyClass

Comment: @FKutsche: Only by convention. That's not part of the rules of the language.

Comment: Yes. that's what i thought .Its a style not a standard .Isn't it?

Comment: Yup. In particular, COM interfaces rarely have the `I`-prefix. I assume that was part of the reason for not making this convention mandatory, though the most important reason is probably "you can't tell if the I is an interface prefix". Ambiguous rules are something C# and .NET tries to avoid very hard.

Comment: Yes for example IEatBurger might be only For EatBurger Not for The person(I)EatBurger